# How to find txnLineID from a transaction in QuickBooks using QBFC/qbXML SDK?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

I want to find out all transactions of a job and make sure the data synced with my application. I use CustomDetailReportQuery to get the data I need. The problem is that the data is in flat hierarchy and the txnID only returns the ID for the transaction. If there are two items in one transaction, they  have the same ID.

Is there anyway to find the txnLineID for each item in the transaction?

I tried to use TransactionQuery, but when I input txnID of the transaction as the search criteria. No items of the transaction are returned.

Thanks.

Comment: I found that IPP QBD V2 has CustomTxnDetail query to include column txnLineId. How come QBFC/qbXML SDK doesn't have it??

Comment: If the question is answered correctly, it would be helpful to others if you accept an answer. Then the question will no longer appear in the `Unanswered Questions` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CustomDetailReportQuery` does not allow retrieving the `txnLineId`.

I think you are looking for `InvoiceQuery` and `SalesReceiptQuery`. This will retrieve the data from Invoices and Sales Receipts that you specify using multiple filters.